# Swing Java component visibility control

Tags: java, swing

I can control the visibility of the frame, but can't control the visibility of component. I can't get the code.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @Umesh Kacha  To 'elaborate' a question, the OP would first need to ask one.

Answer (score 4):

On the contrary, you should be able to control the visibility of a component.  [Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), the base class for most of Swing, contains the [setVisible(boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) method.  Calling `anyComponent.setVisible(false)` will set that component's visibility to false.

You can also [disable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) a component or [remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29) it from the parent container.

*When you do any of these things, make sure to [revalidate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) the parent to make sure it is repainted to reflect your change.*